# Auto layout constraints from intrinsic content size

Tags: ios, constraints, autolayout

Can I specify a constraint saying that a view1's top should be 8 pts from the view's intrinsics content size top rather that view's top?

Comment: I don't think you can, unless the second view have priority for intrinsic size and actually have this size. You should put you background or whatever you need to be bigger than intrinsic size in different view, so your first view have intrinsic size and you be able to align using that

Comment: Your question is not making sense to me. A view's top is not affected by its own size unless you have a constraint that docks the bottom of the view to something else - if that's the case, however, then you'd simply want the height of the view to be 8 pt higher, which you can accomplish by overwriting its `intrinsicContentSize` function.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at overriding the NSView method alignmentRectInsets

By default these insets are zero so we tend to think the intrinsicContentSize means the frame size. But with auto layout you also have an alignment rect which is actually the rect that defines alignment with constraints.

So what you want is an inset of 8 at the top.